Postnominal "of"-phrases: How do I know if they are complements vs. modifiers/adjuncts?
The question is about practical criteria that would differentiate between complements and modifiers/adjuncts in a postnominal setting.  A rule of thumb is said to be that "of" prepositional phrases are complements, but how do I know that this is true?
To put the question on a concrete footing, as an example

He is a student [of English]

"of English" is a complement of the noun "student".  This is justified by drawing a parallel with the verb from which the noun is derived

He studies [English]

where "English" is a complement of the verb "studies".  So far so good.  But what about nouns that are not derived from verbs?  For example

(1) Commentaries on the Laws [of England]
(2) The Morning Readers' Favorite Things [of 2023]

"of England" and "of 2023" refer to place and time, respectively.  And modifiers/adjuncts are said to allow being stacked onto one another, while complements don't.

(3) The Charities Act [of England] [of 1960]

So are these (1-3) complements or modifiers/adjuncts?  What are the practical criteria that would differentiate them?

CGEL's definition includes obligatory and optional complements (p. 221).

@EdwinAshworth CGEL makes no claim that complements must be obligatory. In their Student's Introduction to English Grammar (2nd edition p23), they state quite clearly "Every non-head constituent in a phrase functions as a dependent, but there are many special cases of the dependent function. Two of the most important special cases are complement (an integral and sometimes obligatory part of a phrase that the specific lexical head permits or requires) and adjunct (an optional modifying constituent)." What they do claim is that if a dependent is obligatory, then it is a complement.

@EdwinAshworth Further CGEL p439 states, "while complements of a verb are not infrequently recognisable as such by virtue of being obligatory, the contrast between obligatory and optional elements is of
virtually no relevance to distinguishing complements from modifiers in NP structure."

Thank you to Taro & DW for advice about the  CGEL view. But there have been discussions before on ELU about what a 'complement' actually is. The word has been defined in different ways over the years by different analysts. CGEL use one precising definition, for instance. // As 'He is a student.' is fine standalone, 'of English' is not syntactically obligatory (though the Gricean maxim of quantity may well require it) and so will not be regarded a complement in some analyses.

Related question: Is this prepositional phrase acting as an adjective? ... but DW's answer here is far more saticfactory in delineating the CGEL view on PPs, their identification as modifiers or complements. Though I believe John Lawler would have classed many examples CGEL labels complements as modifiers.

According to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, the distinction between complement and modifier in a noun phrase is not quite so simple as in clause structure.

The distinction between these two kinds of dependent is essentially
the same as in clause structure, but in the NP they are not as clearly
differentiated syntactically. Note in particular that while
complements of a verb are not infrequently recognisable as such by
virtue of being obligatory, the contrast between obligatory and
optional elements is of virtually no relevance to distinguishing
complements from modifiers in NP structure. Compare, for example the
verb peruse and the noun perusal. The former requires an object
(Jill perused the documents, but not * Jill perused), but the noun
can be found quite naturally without a complement: After a quick
perusal, Jill pushed the documents to one side. The one exception is
the noun denizen, which requires a complement: They are denizens of
the forest but not ∗They are denizens.

Their criteria for complements in noun phrases then are:

(a) Complements must be licensed by the head noun
...
(b) Scope of anaphora
In clause structure any internal dependent that can combine with
anaphoric do so must be an adjunct because it takes as antecedent a
verb together with all its internal complements. To a limited extent
the pro-nominal one behaves in the same way in NP structure:
...
(c) Correlation with syntactic category
Within NP structure we do not observe the clause-level correlation
between complement and NP: as we have noted, nouns do not (with minor
exceptions) take NPs as complement. Nevertheless, just as adverbs
typically correspond to adjuncts in the clause, so adjectives are
typically modifiers in the NP: adjectival complements like that in
legal adviser are exceptional.
(d) Positional mobility
Complements are generally more restricted than modifiers. With respect
to the internal dependents of the NP, this is most clearly observable
with pre-head complements, which must be positioned adjacent to the
head noun, following any modifiers. We have for example a brilliant
legal adviser (modifier + complement), but not ∗a legal brilliant
adviser. Post-head complements by contrast only have a tendency to
follow the head noun directly: see §15 below.
(e) Complements express semantic arguments of the head noun
This criterion holds for the NP in much the same way as for the
clause. Its application is particularly straightforward when the
noun is a semantic predicate denoting some property, relation,
process, or action (whether a nominalisation or not), and the
complement represents an involved entity: the bearer of the property,
a term in the rela- tion, etc. However, we also take as complement
those of PPs that are semantically related to the head in such ways
as:
i the dirtiness of the water  [o has non-human property h]
ii the younger sister of Mary [o has kin relation h]
iii the anger of the older staff [o has feeling h]
iv the writing of the book [o is result of h]
v the rays of the sun [o is natural source of h]
vi the spire of the cathedral [o has inherent part h]
vii the most expensive car of the man who lives next door [o is
owner of h]
viii her stupid nitwit of a husband [o is predicand of h]
In the annotations on the right, o = oblique (the NP within the
underlined PP: the water, etc.), and h = head (the head of the
matrix NP: dirtiness, etc.).
...
(f) Semantic roles of complements depend on the head noun
This property of complements is a natural consequence of their being
semantic arguments, and is no less applicable to the NP than to the
clause.
...
(g) Semantic selection restrictions in NPs involve complements
This property too is a natural consequence of the semantic argument
status of comple- ments. A spire is an inherent part of a building,
and this imposes a semantic selection restriction on the denotation of
the complement. While we can have the spire of the cathedral, we
cannot have #the spire of the rocket or #the spire of Mary.

I've omitted some of the extended discussion, but suffice it to say that there's no quick and simple tests to sift the complements from modifiers when it comes to of-phrases as post-head dependent in NPs.

There are hundreds of thousands of hits for "its denizens", but there is a necessary referent (eg 'Mammoth Cave'. And there are fixed phrases (eg 'this is a bit of a nuisance') where dropping the of-phrase changes the sense markedly: one could argue the of-phrase is mandatory.

@DW256 Thanks for the answer.  I am still unable, based on CGEL's criteria, to be sure about my examples.  What would you consider "The laws of England" and "The best things of 2023"?

@TaroYamada The laws of England does seem like a complement according to the criteria: (a) almost any head noun works but the meaning changes to located in or typical of (b) ? The laws of England are different than the ones of my country (c) not applicable (d) it's difficult to insert anything between the head noun laws and of England (e) England does have inherent part laws - all countries have laws (f) yes, England enforces these (g) # the laws of potato, or # the laws of Mars

@TaroYamada the best things of 2023 is more likely a modifier: (a) any head noun would mean originating in or happening in (b) The best things of 2023 don't compare to the ones of 2022 (c) not applicable (d) the best things in technology of 2023 (e) 2023 is not inherent in things (f) not a semantic argument (g) no semantic selection restrictions, though these are a little awkward: the best things of Mars, the best things of potato
